# - I'm unable to click a button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Been trying to  get this to work for a couple of hours now.
its my first real python project so yeh, Would love some help.

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="lyca_cart_newsim_button1" value="FORTSÆT" class="et_pb_more_button et_pb_button lyca_cart_topup_summary" onclick="nc_newsim_open_tab2('payment','sid','tid')">
```

xpath

```
//*[@id='lyca_cart_newsim_button1']
```

This produces error element "not interactable"

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lyca_cart_newsim_button1']").click()
```

This produces no errors but does not click the button

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lyca_cart_newsim_button1']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

This times out

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable
```

First one give `element not interactable`
and the second one gives no errors.

I am using this at a earlier point in the code and its working fine there,

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lyca_cart_newsim_button1']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had good luck using the expected conditions from selenium especially waiting for an element to be clickable.  What I've done whether or not it's best, but it has worked is to have a loop attempt to click and to keep trying within a certain amount of time.  Here is what I use in C#:

```
int timeToTryMilliseconds = 5000;
bool timeNotExpired = true;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

while (timeNotExpired)
     {
          try
               {
                   driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='lyca_cart_newsim_button1']").click()
                   break;
               }
          catch
               {
                    // Half second wait, so it's not polling constantly
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    timeNotExpired = timeToTryMilliseconds > sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
               }
     }
```

If there is a better way, I'd love to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm either the button is in iframe tag. if it is in iframe you must to switch to iframe

if it is not in iframe then try using below code it might work

```
driver.execute_script("$('#lyca_cart_newsim_button1').click()");
```